# What is the default supervised learning training algorithm in matlab?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, supervised-learning

With this code below

```
[x,t] = iris_dataset;
net = patternnet;
net = configure(net,x,t);
net = train(net,x,t); 
save('C:\Temp\trained_net.mat','net');
y = net(x);
perf = perform(net,t,y);
display(['performance: ', num2str(perf)]);
```

I will assume matlab uses its default learning algorithm since i did not specify any. What is the default supervised learning algorithm in matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gathered from the [documentation on `train`](http://mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/train.html) at the bottom in the *more about* section:

> `train` calls the function indicated by `net.trainFcn`, using the training parameter values indicated by `net.trainParam`.

So, you have to indicate it within `net`, which you create yourself.

Additionally you can provide your own [training function](http://mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/trainru.html):

> To prepare a custom network to be trained with `trainru`,
>
> - Set `net.trainFcn` to `'trainru'`. This sets `net.trainParam` to `trainru`'s default parameters.
> - Set each `net.inputWeights{i,j}.learnFcn` to a learning function.
> - Set each `net.layerWeights{i,j}.learnFcn` to a learning function.
> - Set each `net.biases{i}.learnFcn` to a learning function. (Weight and bias learning parameters are automatically set to default values for
>     the given learning function.) To train the network,
> - Set `net.trainParam` properties to desired values.
> - Set weight and bias learning parameters to desired values.
> - Call `train`.